# Развертывание приложения Flask. Gunicorn + Nginx. Debian 8

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, wsgi

Debian 8

Python 2.7

Необходимо развернуть приложение на linux машине.

1

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# app.py

from flask import Flask, send_file, request, Response, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = True

# реализация
...

@app.route('/')
@nocache
def index():
    # реализация
    ...

@app.route('/get-data', methods=['POST'])
def get():
    # реализация
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(filename='error.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
    socket_connection()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Запрос get-data отправляется на сервер каждую секунду.

2

```
# wsgi.py
from app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Gunicorn запускается с помощью запуска следующего сервиса:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve myproject
After=network.target
[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/media/flash/myproject
Environment="PATH=/media/flash/myproject/myprojectenv/bin"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gunicorn --workers 1 --bind unix:myproject.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Конфиг nginx дефолтный. В /etc/nginx/sites-enabled ссылка на файл /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject, который имеет следующее содержание:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name 169.254.5.14;
  location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/media/flash/myproject/myproject.sock;
  }
}
```

Когда перехожу http://169.254.5.14 страничка загружается, но запрос get-data всегда возвращает 500 Internal Server Error.

В чем может быть проблема?

Если запустить только gunicorn без nginx, то все работает.

Comment: А сервис в логе ничего интересного не пишет? `journalctl -u gunicorn-service-name`

Comment: @hoefling, нет, написано только, что сервис запустился.

Comment: @ioprst: попробуйте proxy_pass http://unix:/media/flash/myproject/myproject.sock:; (двоеточие в конце)

Comment: @Ghostik2005, не помогло.

Comment: Кажется проблема в чем-то другом (в методе get). Сейчас обновил реализацию метода get, просто написал return "Hello world", запросы стали проходить.

Comment: Странно, что `gunicorn` ничего не логгирует; попробуй в `ExecStart` добавить ключи `--capture-output --log-level debug --access-logfile /tmp/access.log --error-logfile /tmp/errors.log`. Если 500 ответ идет от гуникорна, значит, где-то в твоей WSGI app кидается необработанное исключение. Я бы настроил логи сначала, чтобы было хотя бы где посмотреть трейс.

Comment: @hoefling, gunicorn не знает флага --capture-output. Или я не так понял?

Comment: Да. В errors.log пошел вывод. Буду разбираться, спасибо

Comment: Да, [`--capture-output`](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#capture-output) был добавлен в версии 19.6; возможно, у тебя просто не самая новая версия, но это не страшно, лишь бы логи писались.

Comment: @hoefling, все заработало, благодарю. Тему с логами можно считать ответом :)

Comment: Отлично, рад был помочь!